# Remove execute permission for x time in Unix

Tags: macos, bash, unix

Is it possible to remove executable permission for a file for a certain amount of time? I would guess it would be implemented in a script but other than `chmod a-x`, I don't know where to go. This is for my Mac so it would be Unix/Bash related.

Comment: For running commands at some point in the future or at periodic intervals, read about the `cron` and `at` commands, both of which should be available on OS X.

Comment: There's nothing that does this automatically. You can write a Launch Daemon that puts back the execute permission after the period of time.

Comment: Why would you want to? This sounds like an XY problem.

Comment: Write a script which removes the "x" and schedules an "at" job to restore the permissions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to remove the permissions for a short period of time you can use something like this:

```
chmod a-x && sleep <number-of-seconds> && chmod a+x
```

You can append `&` and the end to let the command running in background.

If you case is more complicated, you should use a Launch Daemon as suggested in a comment.